# adjust the width of table column in streamlit

Tags: streamlit

I have a table below in streamlit.

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
| --- | --- |
| aaaaaaaaaaaaaa | b |

I wanted to reduce the column width of column1.

Answer (score 2):

This is an open feature request on Streamlit you can see the issue in their github [Ability to set dataframe column width #371](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/371)

A workaround is to use a component for displaying Dataframes called [streamlit-aggrid](https://github.com/PablocFonseca/streamlit-aggrid). Column width can be manually configured by dragging the column header on the front end.